# Update mysql without replacing empty fields

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do an update without replace the empty fields, for examplo, if i have field number 1 and it is empty nothing happens in database but if field number 2 has some content i want it to be updated. the thing happens is when i do it the empty field goes to the database and REPLACE the content of the field for an empty value.

I need an example of how can i do it.

PD: I am using PHP OOP.

This is my query:

```
$conio = "UPDATE affiliates SET nickname = '$nickname', fullname = '$fullname' , email = '$email', skype = '$skype', country = '$country', address = '$address', city = '$city', zip = '$zip', bankname = '$bankname', bankaccount = '$bankaccount', beneficiary = '$beneficiary', username = '$username', password = '$password', whene = '$whene' WHERE id = '$users'";
        mysqli_query($this->link, $conio) or die (mysqli_error($this->link));
```

Comment: When i've done this I simply queried the data previously stored in the row. Then checked every field against the new data. If it changed update it, otherwise update the row with the previous data keeping it the same. I'm unsure if simply updating with NULL avoids updating the field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example: If you want to update the input where the value is not null.

```
<?php
...
$sql = "UPDATE affiliates SET ";
$sql_where = "WHERE id = '$users'";
$sql_set = "";

$firstName = $_POST['firstName']; 
if(!empty($firstName))
   $sql_set .= "firstName = '$firstName',";

$lastName = $_POST['lastName']; 
if(!empty($lastName))
   $sql_set .= "lastName = '$lastName',";
```

and the same thing for all the other inputs ...
...

```
mysql_query($sql.$sql_set.$sql_where);
```

Of course there are better ways of writing this code (ex: using for loop on elements of $_POST), but that's the concept, ...